# ¿Cómo Solucionar problema con graphviz en Python 3.6?

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda, graphviz

Estoy siguiendo algunos tutoriales de Machine Learning con Python (utilizando Jupyter Notebbok con anaconda) y en uno de ellos hay un ejemplo para hacer un árbol de decisiones. todo parece funcionar correctamente hasta que trato de ejecutar la siguientes líneas de código.

```
with open ('arbol.dot') as f:
    dot_graph =f.read()
graphviz.Source(dot_graph)
```

me aparecen los siguientes mensajes de error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py in pipe(engine, format, 
data, quiet)
    153             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
--> 154             startupinfo=STARTUPINFO)
    155     except OSError as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, 
stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, 
universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, 
start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    708                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 709                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    710         except:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, 
preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, 
shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, 
unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    996                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is 
not None else None,
--> 997                                          startupinfo)
998             finally:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo 
especificado

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ExecutableNotFound                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, 
obj)
    334             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    335             if method is not None:
--> 336                 return method()
    337             return None
    338         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py in _repr_svg_(self)
    103 
    104     def _repr_svg_(self):
--> 105         return self.pipe(format='svg').decode(self._encoding)
    106 
    107     def pipe(self, format=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py in pipe(self, format)
    122         data = text_type(self.source).encode(self._encoding)
    123 
--> 124         outs = backend.pipe(self._engine, format, data)
    125 
    126         return outs

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py in pipe(engine, format, 
data, quiet)
    155     except OSError as e:
    156         if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
--> 157             raise ExecutableNotFound(args)
    158         else:  # pragma: no cover
    159             raise

ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the 
Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

Out[8]:
<graphviz.files.Source at 0x185b7555710>
```

ya incluí la ruta (path) de graphviz en las variables de entorno

```
C:\Users\Aspire E15\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\graphviz\
```

ya he instalado varias veces graphviz desde la terminal de anaconda y el resultado es el mismo.

Ojalá me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema para continuar con los tutoriales.

Saludos

Comment: Has probado agregar el path dónde se encuentra el exe de graphvis directamente en el script que estás ejecutando: `import os;os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'`?

Comment: no, no lo he intentado, si la ruta del ejecutable es. C:\Users\Aspire E15\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\graphviz\  como quedaria el codigo?

Comment: Sería así `import os;os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + ' C:\Users\Aspire E15\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\graphviz\' ` revisa por las dudas que el exe no se encuentre en una subcarpeta `bin` en cuyo caso habría que agregarla a dicho path.

Comment: Gracias. Lo intento y te comento el resultado

Comment: Intente agregar la ruta del ejecutable directamente en el script  y el resultado es el mismo. Sigue arrojando el mismo error.